# How to get the execution information of historical queries?

Tags: dolphindb

I want to check some information about the historical queries such as time-consuming, query statements, etc. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may be used DolphinDB in "getRunningQueries" function and "getCompletedQueries"  function

Query the query statement currently running on the node :

```py
getRunningQuerie()
```

Query the query statements that are running on all nodes in the cluster:

```py
pnodeRun(getRunningQueries)
```

Query historical query statements for all nodes in the cluster:

```py
pnodeRun(getCompletedQueries{100})
```